# Doing work in World every frame (FlashPunk/AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

This is probably a newb question, but let's assume I want to make a program that adds an entity every time I click.

My example code would be:

```
package
{
    import net.flashpunk.World;
    import net.flashpunk.utils.Input;

    public class MainWorld extends World
    {
        public function MainWorld()
        {
            trace("world started");
        }
        override public function update():void
        {
            if (Input.mousePressed) add(new blargEntity());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, there's an obvious problem with overriding the update function of the world: the world isn't updating anything.

Is there a way to do work in the World every frame?

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are asking. Are you asking how to call the function "update" in the base class "World"? If so just call super.update()

Comment: Will it run super.update() every frame, though? I guess my real question is how can I check in the world class every frame if the mouse has been pressed or not without overriding any necessary functions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If the `update` function is normally run once per frame, the `super.update()` will make it run as intended so that you can add new functionality in your overridden `update()` function. So yes, add `super.update()` and watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to add a super.update() call like so:

```
    override public function update():void
    {
        if (Input.mousePressed) add(new blargEntity());
        super.update();
    }
```